# python display several variables after %

Tags: python

Folks, cant seem to remember the correct syntax for displaying 2 or more variables in the following format:

```
log.debug ("%s %s " % hostname % processoutput[0])
```

Thanks!

Comment: Error is : TypeError: not enough arguments for format string

Comment: According to the docs, it's not necessary to realize the formatting string before passing it to `debug()`. `log.debug("%s %s ", hostname, processoutput[0])` should work as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want

```
 log.debug ("%s %s " % (hostname , processoutput[0]))
```

a [tuple](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#tuple) should follow the % operator listing all the params to be formatted into the string.

Answer (score 2):

```
log.debug("%s %s" % (hostname, processoutput[0]))
```

Answer (score 2):

You could also do:

```
log.debug('{0} {1}'.format(hostname, processoutput[0]))
```

This might look convoluted at first, but the `format` function is pretty powerful. See [documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language) and [examples](http://docs.python.org/library/string.html#format-examples).